# MAUI App System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread

Tags: c#, hybrid-mobile-app, maui

I receive this error
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread
when run below code
`

```
var image = await Globals.GetImage(attendance.ImageUrl);
                   
                    if(image!= null) 
                    {
                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); 
                        image.CopyTo(ms);
                     **   AttPhoto.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => ms); }**
                   
                    }
```

`

in my static Globals class there is a static method that returns memorystream

Comment: You're probably trying to make the call within a different thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can only update the UI from the main UI thread. If you are running code on a background thread and need to update the UI, you can try to add your code in Main thread.

On Maui,for how to invoke on the main thread , you can check here:

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/7518